# When is the `.constructor` property of an object actually used

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

I've been using code like this for inheriting from another object:

```
// define base object constructor
function SuperType(){
    // constructor code
}

// define base object methods on the prototype
SuperType.prototype.foo = function() {};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// define object that wants to inherit from the SuperType object
function SubType() {
    // call base object constructor with all arguments that might have been passed
    SuperType.apply(this, arguments); 
    // other constructor code
}

// set prototype for this object to point to base object
// so we inherit any items set on the base object's prototype
SubType.prototype = new SuperType();
// reset constructor to point to this object not to SuperType
SubType.prototype.constructor = SubType;

// define any methods of this object by adding them to the prototype
SubType.prototype.myMethod = function() {};
```

My question is why do you have to set the `SubType.constructor = SubType`?  When is the `.constructor` property actually used?  If you create a `SubType` object like this:

```
var s = new SubType();
```

That's going to call the `SubType()` constructor regardless of what `SubType.prototype.constructor` is actually set to, so I'm trying to understand when the `.constructor` property is ever actually used?

---

As you can see in [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Jjc56/) with the assignment to `.constructor` commented out, the proper constructor is still called.  So, it appears that the `.constructor` property is not used in normal construction with the `new` operator.  I'm wondering when it is used?

Comment: I've never seen it used for anything useful and can only guess that it was included as a corollary to *instanceof* (which is also fairly useless).

Comment: @RobG - Hmmm, I thought maybe you were onto something, but `instanceof` doesn't seem to depend upon `.constructor` being set properly: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Qakm7/.

Comment: I have also never seen it being used anywhere. Maybe there are some third party libraries, that use it (which they probably shouldn't) but I don't think that there is something in the language itself that depends on it. It's probably just meant to expose the information about the constructor to the end-user.

Comment: @basilikum - that's what I'm starting to think - not really needed or used and if someone ever used it, the problem could easily be solved another way.  At one point, I thought that maybe it was there so you could know how to arbitrarily create a new object of the same type (without knowing the type by just executing `new obj.constructor()`), but even that only works if you know enough about the type of the object to "know" that no arguments are needed for the constructor or you know which arguments are needed in which case you probably already know enough to create the desired object.

Comment: Well I guess there are some use-cases that could make sense, but it's probably up to you to find/create them. You just have to be aware that you can't rely on this property if you don't have full control over your input data. Anyway, having it not set correctly will most likely not break anything.

Comment: @basilikum - I guess that begs the question to why bother setting the `.constructor` property unless you have a specific use case for that object type.  Just wondering...

Comment: Consistency? Also, if there is any chance that someone else is touching your code in the future, it could be confusing if he tries to access the constructor property, just to find out, that it isn't set correctly. But if you can rule out any specific use case (by you and anybody else), consistency is the only reason I can come up with.

Comment: @basilikum - OK, consistency for the sake of some possible future use is the best reason I can see so far.

Comment: @jfriend00— *instanceof* just checks the prototype chain, hence it's (sort of) complimentary to *constructor*.

Answer (score 1):

According to the The [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.1),

> The initial value of Object.prototype.constructor is the standard built-in Object constructor.

In other words, it's just a pointer to the Object's actual, native constructor-- The one that is called via new Object().  Thus, you can override it without changing anything about how new Object() works.

So why does it exist?  Because constructor functions are effectively classes in JavaScript, it lets you do certain things with class instances without needing to their class name.  To borrow from [Axel Rauschmayer's blog](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/constructor-property.html), the constructor property allows:

- Comparing between classes, i.e. a.constructor === b.constructor
- Creating a new instance from an existing instance, i.e. new a.constructor()
- Invoking another (super)class's constructor

All without any hardcoded references to class names.  Again, it's not really meant to be overridden.  To echo the above comments, I've never really seen someone override it in the wild.