# best way to add back constructor to object.create in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am fully aware of other very similar posts about object.create but I really cannot arrive to answer on this particular question.
I saw a code once where it looks like it was using object.create to create new prototype and then adding back to constructor

```
function blah(){
   // typical constructor
}

blah.prototype = Object.create(somethingelse.prototype);
blah.prototype.constructor = blah;
```

Something like that .. and I tried that in chrome dev tool but did not see them as equal.. Now trying to see what that code I did see was trying to accomplish? I assume there is more difference in Object create and new(than just missing constructor?)

```
function blah(){
 //...
}
undefined
function somethingelse(){
 //
}
undefined
somethingelse.prototype = {
    // something else
}
Object {}
blah.prototype = Object.create(somethingelse.prototype);
Object {}
blah.prototype.constructor = blah;
blah(){
 //...
}
blah == somethingelse;
false
```

Comment: `blah` and `somethingelse` are two different functions. Why do you think they both would be equal/same?

Comment: actually I meant to post the one w/ new .. doing it now

Comment: actually I was confused and now I clearly see what that code did.It wanted to get prototype out of something else but still add back it's own constructor(which is different from somethingelse's).

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Area you trying to inherit from somethingelse?  Or just create an instance of somethingelse?  Do you understand the difference between those two?

Comment: I guess that code was trying to inherit from some other's prototype but still be able to add back it's own constructor(which is not possible if one were to use the 'new' to build the object).

Comment: I'm guessing that you should read [What it the significance of the Javascript constructor property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property) and [When is the `.constructor` property of an object actually used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186731/when-is-the-constructor-property-of-an-object-actually-used).  It's barely used and doesn't generally affect the behavior of the object at all.  When declaring a derived prototype, it is customary to set it to the new constructor, but it is hardly ever used in real practice.

Comment: Thank you. Checking them out

Answer (score 0):

You've created two different objects (blah and something).
I think you are confused about what [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) means.

when you compare (==) 2 objects the reference is being evaluated - and it is different.